# How to create a type definition for a string in c

Tags: c, typedef

I have this datatype I call **ItemType** which is a string.

```
typedef <string> ItemType
```

I am not sure what to put into the "string>" part. I've tried the following:
    `typedef char[] ItemType` and 
    `typedef char* ItemType`
neither of them works.

**Itemtype** is used for an arraylist I am creating in C, indicating what datatype the elements of the Arraylist has. The arraylist itself is generic as it accepts whatever **ItemType** is and is implemented in a .c file while **Itemtype** is in the .h header file.

EDIT 1 .c Implementation code snippets:

```
struct list_type {
    ItemType* data;
    int size;  
    int capacity;
};


// adds a component to the array, if enough memory available

void push(ListType listptr, ItemType item) {  
    if (listptr->size >= listptr->capacity) {
        ItemType * temp = malloc(sizeof(ItemType) * (listptr->capacity + 200));
        if (temp != NULL) {
              listptr->capacity += 200;
              memcpy(temp, listptr->data,sizeof(ItemType) * (listptr->size));
              free(listptr->data);
              listptr->data = temp;
              listptr->data[listptr->size] = item;
              listptr->size++;
              printf("%s inserted:%s ", item, listptr->data[listptr->size]);
        }
    }

    else {
         listptr->data[listptr->size] = item;
         listptr->size++;
         printf("%s inserted:%s ", item, listptr->data[listptr->size]);
    }

}

void printl(ListType listptr) {
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < listptr->size; i++) printf("%s ", listptr->data[i]);
  printf("\n");

}
```

EDIT .h header file snippets

```
typedef struct list_type *ListType;
typedef char* ItemType;
//other code
void push(ListType l, ItemType item);
```

Comment: what do you mean by neither of them works? Do you get an error or a wrong behaviour?

Comment: Can you provide an error message and a relevant code snippet?

Comment: @Nadir when I push a string into the arraylist, it doesn't store the actual string. i.e. I push "John"  into the arraylist and the value is null for that element.

Comment: The typedef syntax corresponds to the normal declaration syntax for identifiers. Instead of an object identifier, a type identifier is declared though. Your `typedef char* ItemType;` should work. Your `typedef char[] ItemType` is C# syntax and illegal in C. I'm also not sure whether the absence of an array size (in correct syntax, like `typedef char ItemType[]`) is possible, and if so, whether it would declare an incomplete array type or a pointer type.

Comment: Post a code snippet where you use ItemType and you push it into the arraylist

Comment: `typedef (char*) ItemType`  should work

Comment: @Nadir posted code snippet of the .c implementation.

Comment: If you declare `ItemType` as `char*`, you dont need to do `ItemTYpe * ..`, because that way you are creating a char **. Try using `ItemType temp = malloc...`

Comment: @Nadir i added the .h header snippets. pushed a string "John" in and got null. In the terminal it printed: `John inserted:(null) `

Comment: When printing, you are taking the data from `listptr->size`, which points to the tail of the arraylist (which has no element). If you want the last element, do `printf("%s inserted:%s ", item, listptr->data[listptr->size - 1]);`

Comment: @Nadir oh I see, that makes sense. Thanks. Also if wanted to print the entire arraylist would it just be this: `for(i = 0; i < listptr->size; i++)
    printf("%s ", listptr->data[i]);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105808/discussion-between-s-d-and-nadir).

Comment: You are re-implementing c++'s std::vector, kindof. By changing the typedef for ItemType it's almost a template ;-).

Answer (score 11):

It depends on what you mean by "string".

If you mean an array of `char` that can be passed to functions like `strcpy()`, it is easy

```
  typedef char ItemType[10];
```

declares `ItemType` to be an array of `char`, which can hold any C-style string for which `strlen()` returns `9` or less (the difference of `1` is due to the terminating `'\0'` terminator that string related functions (`strcmp()`, `strcat()`, `strlen()`) look for to mark the end of the string).

The limitation is that the size is fixed.    Write 20 characters to an `ItemType` (e.g. using `strcpy()`) and behaviour is undefined.   It is your responsibility to ensure too many characters are not written to an `ItemType`.

If you mean some type that can hold an arbitrary length string, where YOUR code has to manage things to ensure the data storage is large enough, you can do things like

```
  typedef char *ItemType;
```

The problem with this is that your code needs to manage the memory that pointer points at.    `ItemType` is a pointer, not an array which can hold data.

```
 #include <stdlib.h>    /*  declares malloc(), realloc(), free(), etc */

 /*   and in a function somewhere */
 
 ItemType x = malloc(25);

  /*   can use any operations that do not copy more than 24 characters to x  */
  /*  but if we want a larger string, we have to manage it   */

  ItemType temp = realloc(x, 50);

  if (temp == NULL)   /*  reallocation failed */
  {
       /* work out how to recover or terminate */
  }
  else
  {
       x = temp;
  } 

   /*  If reallocation failed and no recovery is done, do not execute the following code */

  /* can now treat x as an array of 50 characters (i.e. if we ensure strlen(x) never exceeds 49 */


  free(x);    /*  when we are done with x */
```

If you want a string type that will resize itself as needed (e.g. as provided by some other languages) then there is no way in C.

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef char* ItemType
```

actually means ItemType = char*.

So basically you have created just another name for char*. ItemType itself is not a variable but a data type. Following is the usage of typedef

```
int main()
{
    typedef char* itemType;

    itemType str = (char*) malloc(50);
    strcpy(str, "Hello World");

    printf("%s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C, don't cast the result of `malloc()`.   It causes undefined behaviour if you have forgotten to `#include <stdlib.h>`.   If you `#include <stdlib.h>` the cast is not required (unless you are using a C++ compiler).